# PyDev interactive Console 'runfile' error

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

when i try to run code in the interactive console using Alt+Ctrl+Enter it gives that error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'runfile' is not defined
```

using python 2.7.6
eclipse 4.4
PyDev 3.7

Comment: Does it happen if you click on Run->Run or Ctrl+F11?

Comment: no it runs in the default console perfectly

Comment: what's in your Run->'Run Configuration' MainModule field?

Comment: ${workspace_loc:andre/and.py}

Comment: I have this in my Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interactive Console: "import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))" sys.executable will be used to run your code and may be adding this will help in yours. You can try and see.

Comment: /usr/bin/python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2]

Comment: no this is just a welcoming msg , when you press CTRL+ALT+ENTER does it run your code or does it gives the same error , if it runs would please tell me what versions you are working with ? and when you type runfile() what does it tells you ?

Comment: Eclipse: Juno Service Release 2, Build id: 20130225-0426. PydeV:2.7.5.2013052819. Python:2.7.2

Answer (score 1):

This is really a bug in PyDev 3.7 (and 3.7.1).

The next version should have it fixed. You can apply the change: https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/commit/06fb7661875f27ae72aba6e037bb353a8629633c locally to have it fixed in your local installation (that file is in org.python.pydev/pysrc/pydevconsole.py)

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be related to the latest Pydev version 3.7

I have experienced the same problem on 2 installations after upgrading Pydev from 3.6 to 3.7

Eclipse 4.3.2
Python 2.7.6 and 3.4.0
Pydev upgraded from 3.6 to 3.7

After uninstalling Pydev 3.7 and reinstalling version 3.6 the problem is gone for me.